# AngularJS not working with MVC Partial Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am having a strange problem. I am using AngularJS in my project. I have some partial views where I am having different implementations of AngularJS functionality. I am loading all my partial views via Ajax call. Ajax call does load partial view in container but its AngularJS functionality does not work. I have noticed that when I give reference to AngularJS via CDN then it works but when I copy and paste CDN JS into my local js file then it does not.

Please suggest what is the issue.

Here is the code:

Partial View:

```
<div ng-controller="EmployeeController">
    <div>
        ID: <input type="text" id="txtID" ng-model="employeeID" /><br />
        Name: <input id="txtName" type="text" ng-model="employeeName" />
        <button id="btnAddEmployee" ng-click="addEmployee()">Add Employee</button>
        <button id="btnRemoveEmployee" ng-click="removeEmployee()">Remove Employee</button>
        <ul >
            <li ng-repeat="employee in employees">
               Employee id is: {{employee.id}}<br />
               Employee name is: {{employee.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var employees = [{ name: 'ABC', id: '1' },
                    { name: 'XYZ', id: '2' },
                    { name: 'KKK', id: '3' }];

    function EmployeeController($scope) {
        $scope.employees = employees;
        $scope.addEmployee = function () {
            $scope.employees.push({ name: $scope.employeeName, id: $scope.employeeID });
        }
        $scope.removeEmployee = function () {
            $scope.employees.pop();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult LoadViews(int id)
{
    if (id == 1)
        return PartialView("TestView1Partial");
    else 
        return PartialView("TestView2Partial");
}
```

Main View:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="LoadView2()">View 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="dvContainer">
```

```
<script>
    function LoadView2() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/home/LoadViews?id=2",
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "html",
            async:true,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#dvContainer").html(result);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Thanks,
JSHunjan

Comment: So the problem is that Angularjs doesn't work when you change from using the CDN to using a local version of your file?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem I am facing.

Comment: How are you importing your angular.js local file? You wrote a big question for a simple question.

Comment: Your path to the angularjs file is wrong. Please post the path that you are using.

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan I am using JS file by dragging and dropping from scripts folder to the view. I dont think visual studio will create wrong path. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Here is the path of my js file
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: @JSHunjan Remove the `~` and try, make it look like <script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: Did you manager to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax call change the `async:false` and it might work.