# How to load MVC Partial View and keep Angular JS working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

How should I load mvc partial views and keep Angular JS working.
Angular JS is working fine after I render the layout, but if I load partial views in the layout, Angular JS is not working anymore in the partials.
I guess that Angular engine is not compiling the ng- directives after I inject the HTML in the DOM.

Comment: How do you inject the HTML?

Comment: @arnolrob The question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312523/angularjs-not-working-with-mvc-partial-views

Comment: First I was injecting using jQuery $('#id').html(data), then I changed to angular.element('#id').html(data). Also tried to compile var element = angular.element(data); $compile(element)($scope); angular.element("#id").html(element);

Comment: @kanchirk Yeap thanks, I already took a look over that post, unfortunately it wasn't helpful in my situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of inject your HTML manually. Be it through angular.element.html or $().html. Try using one of the following, angular approved, options:

- A routing engine like [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or ui-router. The engine can include a template which is rendered by the backend.
- The [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive. This way you can include HTML templates directly.
- Write a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) which injects your HTML.

Because these are AngularJS friendly methods, Angular will actually parse the HTML and bind any values within the newly loaded HTML.

Comment: Both of this method are pretty hard to implement at this point. it is an ASP.NET MVC application with configurable menu. So routing will be very hard to implement on client side and also templates. Sorry. Any other ideea? :D

Comment: I'm assuming you're making a GET HTTP request to the .NET backend which in its turn returns HTML to AngularJS. Instead of making the request yourself have the ngInclude directive (native in AngularJS) resolve the HTML for you. You can link the src to a variable so you can switch the included HTML.

For more information see this answer as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21860569/2637098

Comment: I was trying something like this <div ng-include="''{selectedUrl}"></div> and selecting a specific menu assign the url to $scope.selectedUrl. This is not working. Am I getting this aproach worng?

Comment: use a method to return selectedUrl (getSelectedUrl maybe?) to the directive. This will trigger an $apply when selectedUrl is changed. Which in its turn should refresh the content.

Comment: At least am I on the rigth track? I am referring to the previous comment

Comment: It is exaclty the way I do that. The problem is that in this case you include a html file, and I am trying to include a url which is a request to the back-end. And not sure if this is not a problem.

Comment: your example it works now. Thanks a lot. Can you help me out with another issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/3nLaPhiw7PflMmFl6eZ6?p=info see this plunker

Comment: I'm not near a computer in the upcoming three hours. So not much help from my side. I guess it might have to do with the scope. My suggestion is to have a look at John Papas opinionated style guide. The refactoring might take some time but it'll surely be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

From an answer from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/2010986.aspx?AngularJS%20in%20ASP%20NET%20MVC%20Partial%20View)

I think you may need to compile HTML string or DOM into a template.

More information, please refer to:

## $compile

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

There are some threads that may help you:

## AngularJS - Dynamically creating elements that specify directives

[AngularJS - Dynamically creating elements that specify directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025526/angularjs-dynamically-creating-elements-that-specify-directives)

## Bind Angularjs to newly created html element dynamically

[Bind Angularjs to newly created html element dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867554/bind-angularjs-to-newly-created-html-element-dynamically)