# Partial Views in Angular JS MVC project

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am a newbie to Dot Net MVC and I am trying to re-build my razor views using Angular JS. But there is something I am stuck with. 
I have imported the Angular JS Core library in my project 
[image]

And I have referenced the same in the BundleConfig.cs class also.

```
        //Added for angular reference
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
        "~/Scripts/angular.min.js"));
```

In my custom layout page **_myTemplateLayoutPage.cshtml** this is reflected via :

```
<html ng-app="">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Prank Systems Pvt. Ltd.</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/myTemplate/")style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
```

But when I try to load a partial view, Angular on the partial is not working.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_myTemplateLayoutPage.cshtml";
    }


<h2>Index Details</h2>
<input type="text" ng-model="name" />
{{name}}
```

I understand I am not referencing ng-app in my partial view but that's referenced in the layout page.

Here's what I get when run in browser :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load MVC Partial View and keep Angular JS working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123417/how-to-load-mvc-partial-view-and-keep-angular-js-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename your angular script name from `angular.min.js` to `angular.js`:

And then in your `BundleConfig.cs`:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
    "~/Scripts/angular.js"));
```

The main reason of this issue is because Bundler is not including `min` files, and, your angular library doesn't get included on your project.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder, i'm glad to help...i face the exact same problem a few weeks ago :)